# Python, how train_test_split works?

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn

i'm newbie in Python, i have question why this block of code works in this way.

```
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(
df.drop(labels=[21], axis=1),
df[21],
test_size=0.2,
random_state=37
```

)
I want to make 5-fold cross validation. My df contians matrix. I have no idea why after printing each variable `print(train_features)
print(test_features)
print(train_labels)
print(test_labels)`

I get data in different format, for train_features and test_features is something like that:

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ...  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20

3       2   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   2  ...   1   2   3   2   2   1   3   3   2

395   2   3   2   3   2   1   1   2   1  ...   2   1   1   1   2   3   2   1   1

186   2   3   1   1   2   2   2   2   2  ...   2   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   1

and for train_labels and test_labels something like that:

3       1

395    20

186     9

6       1
My question is why here i'm getting once matrix with 20 columns and once with only 2.
Can you explain how this code works? I'm freshman in Python sorry.

Comment: test_train_split just splits your data into two parts.  What is wrong with the output youre getting?

Comment: Please help us what exactly you mean by "different format"

Comment: while I'm printing variables train_features and test_feature I get matrix [n rows x  20 columns] but when I'm printing variables train_labels and test_labels I get only 2 columns. I think that I assign to variables the same data format

Comment: for example  x, y, z, = random.randInt(1,10)  is it not similar? My question is why here i'm getting once matrix with 20 columns and once with only 2

Answer (score 0):

That is complety expected, when you run a classifier or regression you always have input features: `X`, which are providing an output `y`: `X --> y`.

In your case your input features are:
`train_features, test_features` which have 21 features with your matrix:

```
train_features = (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

                  2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 ... 1 2 3 2 2 1 3 3 2

                  2 3 2 3 2 1 1 2 1 ... 2 1 1 1 2 3 2 1 1

                  2 3 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ... 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1
```

and your label (targets) with one output:

```
train_labels = (1

                20

                9

                1 )
```

The first column is probably your row index. So the mapping is:
`train_features --> train_labels`
`test_features --> test_labels`
What has the same shape/dimension is train_features / test_features and train_labels / test_labels